# numpy.dtype vs numpy.ndarray.dtype

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a simple issue using `np.dtype`, demonstrated in the following code piece:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [2]: var = np.arange(5, dtype=np.int32)                                                                                                                                                                         

In [3]: print(var)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[0 1 2 3 4]

In [4]: print(var.dtype)                                                                                                                                                                                           
int32

In [5]: print(np.dtype(var))                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-03f3349b4160> in <module>
----> 1 print(np.dtype(var))

TypeError: data type not understood
```

Why am I getting two different results?

Comment: `numpy.dtype`'s purpose is to create a `dtype` object, not to return the `dtype` of an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @yatu in comments, `numpy.dtype` will not return the datatype of an array. It only creates dtype objects. On the other hand, `ndarray.dtype` returns and array datatype. To understand this better, here is a sample code:

```
a = np.dtype(np.int16)
b = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
c = np.array([1., 2., 3.], a)
```

Note how dtype object `a` is passed to array `c` when it is created.

output:

```
a: int16
b.dtype: float64
c.dype: int16
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.dtype()` is the constructor for creating a data-type-object, whereas the type of numpy array `var` can be accessed via `var.dtype`

You may find more information in the [numpy manual](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html) or by looking into the docstring:

> numpy.dtype(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Docstring:
>   dtype(obj, align=False, copy=False)
>
> Create a data type object.
>
> A numpy array is homogeneous, and contains elements described by a
>   dtype object. A dtype object can be constructed from different
>   combinations of fundamental numeric types.
>   [...]